# How to use a view multiple times?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS.

I'm adding views to the controller using the code below.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CollapseClickDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIView *test1view;
    IBOutlet UIView *test2view;

    __weak IBOutlet CollapseClick *myCollapseClick;
}
```

I need to create 50 different instances of the view located below. How can I do this? I looked into subviews but as I said at the top I'm a newbie and couldn't figure out what was going on.

-Name:
-Amount:
-Percent:

Comment: If you're using a view 50 times are you sure you want to be using IBOutlets for each one? You can create a custom UIView that you insert on the page programmatically.

Comment: I actually wanted to make 50 programmatically. How would I do that? I'm currently using a plugin called CollapseClick and I only know how to add views through the code located above. I'll research custom classes now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

To create your views programatically, use `viewDidLoad:` of your `UIViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        //provide some initial frame, set the correct frames in viewWillLayoutSubviews: 
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,i*10;100;5);
        //create a new UIView, use your own UIView subclass here if you have one
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        //set it's backgroundColor in case you are copy&pasting this code to try it out, so you see that there are actually views added ;)
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        //add it to the viewController's view
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        //you might consider creating an NSArray to store references to the views for easier access in other parts of the code
    }
}
```

To create a view that you designed in a storyboard use something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390131/3659846

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyScene"]; 
[self.view addSubView:myViewController.theViewToAdd];
```

To create a view from a `nib` file, use the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11836614/3659846

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourNib" owner:nil options:nil];
UIView *view = [nibContents lastObject]; //assuming the nib contains only one view
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    UIView *someView = [UIView new];
    // this positions each view one under another with height 40px and width 320px like a table
    [someView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,40*i,320,40)];
    // set other view properties 
    // put a UILabel on the view
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,20)];
    [view addSubview:label];
    // set label properties
    [self.view addSubview:someView]
}
```

Note the frame is relative to its parent view coordinate system and you need to add the view to its parent view by calling addSubview: method. -good luck